# On cloudflare I want to disable caching and see my website changes immediately that I've pushed live

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, cloudflare

On cloudflare I want to disable caching and see my website changes immediately that I've pushed live.

**Things I've tried:**

- I've put development mode on.
- Create a bypass on caching in page rules.
- Purged an individual webpage.
- Purged the website.
- Set cache to clear every 2 hours.

None of the above worked.

**Tech I'm using:**

- Angular2
- SystemJS
- Typescript which becomes javascript on build.
- Firebase for hosting and database.
- Cloudflare for SSL etc.

The only way people see my website changes, it if they hard refresh.

The main problem is I've got a javascript file called app.js and its has all my javascript in for my Angular app. And it doesnt seem like its trying to get the resource in the browser.

I've changed the app.js to app.js?1490959855777
And still doesnt fetch the file again.

I basically want to see my JS file without a user having to hard refresh.

[image]

Comment: Seems like my index.html is cache in the browsers. So I would need to cache bust the index.html page

Comment: Have you regenerated app.js from the new source files?

Comment: @Jules not new files - but I've updated the javascript and html for example and its not coming through

Comment: @Jules the index.html page is fine and doesnt seem to cache. But cloudflare seems to stop browsers getting the latest js files and html even though they are cache bust urls e.g. app.js?1234567 and shim.js?123455. This is my website: https://thepoolcover.co.uk/

Comment: Can you dupe index.html as index.php (or other dynamic extension)? Give that a shot. Otherwise - do you have page rules stating to cache html pages? Can you give us the URL to check out?

Comment: @Jules I've added my page rule in the screen shot above. I want all web pages not to be cached. Does that look right above?

Comment: @Jules the url is: https://thepoolcover.co.uk

Comment: @Jules It definitely cloudflare, because I have a dev environment that has no cloudflare and theirs no caching

Comment: If a regular refresh (F5) does not get you the new file, but hard refresh (shift+F5) does, it means the file is cached in your browser - not in cloudflare.

Comment: @Jules how can I stop this hard refresh scenario happening for all my users. I don't want to email them all saying hard refresh to get the latest features on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion above, it looks like the caching is happening on the browser - since a hard refresh will get the new file contents.

I think what happened is CF told the browser to hold onto that file for a very log time. And the browser is listening to that request.

Because you can't ask your users to do a hard refresh, you'll need to rename the static files that are being cached so aggressively.

Comment: So should I rename my index.html file to index1.html? I'm using angular2 so I only have one static page

Comment: I've never used Angular. I don't think it will matter what you rename that file to - the CDN, and browsers, look at the URL to determine caching. And if I'm looking at this correctly, angular plays with the url to give a fancy user experience. Because it's the url `thepoolcover.co.uk` that is being cached, and not a static resource (like jpg, css, etc), it's not possible to rename.